# My PC is not turning on at home but works perfectly fine at the repair shop

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, amd-ryzen

My PC is not turning on at home but works perfectly fine at the repair shop. I went to the shop many times, when I bring it back from the shop and try to turn it on, sometimes it turns on for the first time but doesn't work afterwards, the technician came home and checked with new PSU and power cable, but still not working.

They send the motherboard for warranty, but the company sent it back saying it works perfectly. I took it to my neighbor's and friends' homes, still not turning on. (No turning on means the led strip on the motherboard lights up but the fans don't work, all of them, front panel light doesn't work, RAM and SSD doesn't turn on).

Tried changing RAM slot position, CMOS battery, still not working.

> ```
>  ASUS Prime B550M motherboard
>  RYZEN 7 5700G (integrated graphics)
>  16 GB RAM x1
>  500 GB SSD
> ```

Comment: Different AC Voltages?

Comment: Is this a new problem or did it never work properly at home?

Comment: If you remove the RAM and try to boot, does the computer emit a beep code?  If yes, that's at least a good sign that it's POSTing.  If no beep codes, turn the computer off and unplug the power cable.  Hold down the power button for a few seconds (do this a few times), plug the power cable in and try booting again.  You could also try a PSU tester to see what's happening when the computer doesn't turn on at your house.

Comment: you are describing a problem that is caused by something external to the PC case ... stop messing with the RAM and with the CMOS battery and start looking at power and at external devices

Comment: What PSU's?  Have you tried a power filter or UPS?  Its an interrsting one, but it sounds like your power is very noisy or otherwise out of spec. (The "correct" step is to get someone to check that the power is clean and can handle the current I imagine. More something an Electrical Engineer ir clued up sparky would do.

Comment: Question - is your neighbour in the same building as you?

Comment: get a non-digital outlet tester

Comment: It's a new problem , I have only been using it for 10 months - @AndrewMorton

Comment: The outlet is connected to the UPS .   there is no beeb code while turning on with or without ram ( the speaker are powered using an adaptor) but there is a tiny buzz noise from the speaker  and it stops when I unplug the power cable)

Comment: @Visalvyasan Did any other electrical equipment in your home start having problems at the same time as your computer did? If the computer works at the shop and not in your home then the problem is most likely with the mains electricity in your home. It looks like the technician's actions when they came to your home and the PC still did not work supports that.

Comment: @Visalvyasan Does the PC work without the UPS? Does the UPS have a self-test function?

Comment: I tried plugging it in to the socket which is not connected to the UPS , still not working, no problem with other appliances,my wifi and monitor are powered from the same panel of sockets